# Execute code after function execution in angularjs

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova

I'm making application for iOS using Phonegap with SQLite.
In deviceready(), I'm loading SQLite table from the JSON file.

CODE:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

var db;

function onDeviceReady() {
  try
  {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 2048*1024, FileIO.gotFS, FileIO.errorHandler);

        db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: "ValeDB", location: 1 });

        db.transaction(function(tx) {

                       tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_Location');
                       tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_OrgUnit');
                       tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_Location (id integer, value text)');
                       tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_OrgUnit (id integer, value text, type text)');

                       LocationList.forEach(function(loc){
                                            //console.log(loc.value);
                                            tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO tbl_Location (id, value) VALUES (?, ?)", [loc.id, loc.value],
                                                          function(tx, res){
                                                            //console.log("Success: " + res.insertId);
                                                          },
                                                          function(e){
                                                            console.log("Error: " + e.message);
                                                          });
                                            });

                       tx.executeSql("SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count FROM tbl_Location", [], function(tx, res){
                                     if(res.rows.length > 0)
                                        console.log("New rows added to tbl_Location:" + res.rows.item(0).Count);
                                     });

                       EnglishOrgUnit.forEach(function(org){
                                            //console.log(loc.value);
                                            tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO tbl_OrgUnit (id, value, type) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [org.id, org.value, "en"],
                                                          function(tx, res){
                                                          //console.log("Success: " + res.insertId);
                                                          },
                                                          function(e){
                                                          console.log("Error: " + e.message);
                                                          });
                                            });

                       tx.executeSql("SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count FROM tbl_OrgUnit WHERE TYPE = 'en'", [], function(tx, res){
                                     if(res.rows.length > 0)
                                     console.log("New Eng. rows added to tbl_OrgUnit:" + res.rows.item(0).Count);
                                     });

                       PortugueseOrgUnit.forEach(function(org){
                                              //console.log(loc.value);
                                              tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO tbl_OrgUnit (id, value, type) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [org.id, org.value, "pt"],
                                                            function(tx, res){
                                                            //console.log("Success: " + res.insertId);
                                                            },
                                                            function(e){
                                                            console.log("Error: " + e.message);
                                                            });
                                              });

                       tx.executeSql("SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count FROM tbl_OrgUnit WHERE TYPE = 'pt'", [], function(tx, res){
                                     if(res.rows.length > 0)
                                     console.log("New Port. rows added to tbl_OrgUnit:" + res.rows.item(0).Count);
                                     });
                     });

    }
  catch(e)
  {
        console.log("Error:" + e.message)
  }
}
```

Config:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.Vale.Incident" version="1.1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="false" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value=".25" />
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
<preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />
<preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false" />
<preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="gray" />
<preference name="GapBetweenPages" value="0" />
<preference name="PageLength" value="0" />
<preference name="PaginationBreakingMode" value="page" />
<preference name="PaginationMode" value="unpaginated" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
<feature name="LocalStorage">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocalStorage" />
</feature>
<name>ReportIncident</name>
<description>
    Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.
</description>
<author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
    PhoneGap Team
</author>
<preference name="permissions" value="none" />
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.5.0" />
<preference name="orientation" value="default" />
<preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
<preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="blue" />
<preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
<preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
<preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />
<!--gap:plugin name="com.millerjames01.sqlite-plugin"-->
<!--plugin name="SQLitePlugin" value="SQLitePlugin" /-->
<icon src="icon.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="blackberry" src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
<icon gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover" src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="res/icon/ios/vale-57.png" width="57" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="res/icon/ios/vale-72.png" width="72" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="res/icon/ios/vale-114.png" width="114" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="res/icon/ios/vale-144.png" width="144" />
<icon gap:platform="webos" src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" />
<icon gap:platform="winphone" src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" />
<icon gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="blackberry" src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="res/screen/ios/splash5-320-480.png" width="320" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="res/screen/ios/splash5-320-480.png" width="640" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1136" src="res/screen/ios/splash5-320-480.png" width="640" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="res/screen/ios/splash5-320-480.png" width="768" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="res/screen/ios/splash5-320-480.png" width="1024" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="winphone" src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.statusbar" version="0.1.4" />
<gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.videocaptureplus" />
<access origin="*" />
<feature name="Camera">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCamera" />
</feature>
<feature name="Notification">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVNotification" />
</feature>
<preference name="CameraUsesGeolocation" value="false" />
<feature name="Vibration">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVVibration" />
</feature>
<feature name="File">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFile" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
<feature name="Capture">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCapture" />
</feature>
<feature name="NetworkStatus">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVConnection" />
</feature>
<plugin name="Notification" value="CDVNotification" />
<feature name="FileTransfer">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFileTransfer" />
</feature>
<feature name="File">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFile" />
</feature>
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
</feature>
<feature name="Globalization">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVGlobalization" />
</feature>
<feature name="Media">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSound" />
</feature>
<feature name="Console">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLogger" />
</feature>
<feature name="VideoCapturePlus">
    <param name="ios-package" value="VideoCapturePlus" />
</feature>
<feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar" />
</feature>
<feature name="Device">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVDevice" />
</feature>
<feature name="SQLitePlugin">
    <param name="ios-package" value="SQLitePlugin" />
</feature>
<plugin name="SQLitePlugin" value="SQLitePlugin" />
</widget>
```

Problem:
Before the tables are completely loaded, the User is redirected to the Login page

Expected:
User is redirected to the Login page, only once the data is completely loaded. Till that time the Splash screen should be displayed to the user.

Any idea how to go about it

Thanks in advance

Comment: How can we delay the hiding of the screen till the data is completely loaded or is there any other approach to go about it?

Comment: Have you already configured splashscreen plugin?

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if that helped.

Comment: JSON files contains more than 10,000 records.

Comment: Yes, made use of <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480"  width="320" src=".." /> in config.xml

Answer (score 0):

In your `config.xml` add this line

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
```

And use this function in your js when you want to hide splashscree
`navigator.splashscreen.hide();`

Comment: Not helping, still navigating  :(

Comment: Yes, thing is when the splash screen hides the data starts loading into the SQLite.

Comment: can you please add your config.xml in question.

Comment: Updated question with Config.xml

Comment: You are using `<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />` at 4th line, please remove that.

Comment: You also have `<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />` please remove that too.